# Общие элементы списков из словарей Python

Tags: python, словари

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой поиска оптимального решения задачи, заключающиеся в поиске совпадений в списках, состоящих из словарей.
Для примера есть два списка: в первом списке два словаря, во втором один. Нужно проверить, если ли у этих списков общие словари. Операции со множествами здесь не подходят, т.к элементами являются словари. Также хочется обойтись без перебора элементов через циклы. Варианты списков: есть общие элементы, нет общих элементов, списки полностью совпадают, пустые списки.
Пример исходных данных:

```
a = [
    {
              "field_id": 664395,
              "field_code": "1234",
              "field_type": "text",
              "values": [
                {
                  "value": "yutyuyt",
                  "enum_code": "WORK"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "field_id": 664393,
              "field_code": "4321",
              "field_type": "int",
              "values": [
                {
                  "value": "203040",
                  "enum_id": 1072543,
                  "enum_code": "WORK"
                }
              ]
    }
]


b = [
    {
              "field_id": 664395,
              "field_code": "1234",
              "field_type": "text",
              "values": [
                {
                  "value": "yutyuyt",
                  "enum_code": "WORK"
                }
              ]
            }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант использовать комбинацию из Lambda и Filter функций

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: x in b, a)))
```

Результат

```
[{'field_id': 664395, 'field_code': '1234', 'field_type': 'text', 'values': [{'value': 'yutyuyt', 'enum_code': 'WORK'}]}]
```

Comment: красиво, но это не цикл разве внутри?

Comment: @Сергей я так понял, автор хочет избавиться от цикла в традиционном их понимании. Возможно есть и более подходящее решение :)

Comment: я так понял, что автор в скорости хочет выиграть, но вот только я сомневаюсь, что без перебора нехешируемый тип сравнить вообще можно.

Answer (score 1):

В данном примере не выполнены условия топикстартера это
к комментарию @Сергей про нехэшируемый тип

```py
from typing import Iterable

a = [
    {
        "field_id": 664395,
        "field_code": "1234",
        "field_type": "text",
        "values": [
            {
                "value": "yutyuyt",
                "enum_code": "WORK"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "field_id": 664393,
        "field_code": "4321",
        "field_type": "int",
        "values": [
            {
                "value": "203040",
                "enum_id": 1072543,
                "enum_code": "WORK"
            }
        ]
    }
]

b = [
    {
        "field_id": 664395,
        "field_code": "1234",
        "field_type": "text",
        "values": [
            {
                "value": "yutyuyt",
                "enum_code": "WORK"
            }
        ]
    }
]

from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass()
class DictItem:
    field_id: int
    field_code: str
    field_type: str
    values: list

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(
            (self.field_id,
            self.field_code,
             self.field_type,
             # сюда еще можно добавить сортировку при создании кортежа
             # в этом случае изначальный порядок полей будет не важен
             tuple((k, v) for elem in self.values for k, v in elem.items())
             )
        )


aset = set(map(lambda x: DictItem(**x), a))
bset = set(map(lambda x: DictItem(**x), b))

res, *_ = aset & bset
print(asdict(res))

# {'field_id': 664395, 'field_code': '1234', 'field_type': 'text', 'values': [{'value': 'yutyuyt', 'enum_code': 'WORK'}]}
```